# Adjective + to meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context, adjectives

A sentence from my textbook

> These people **are slow to** change their mind.

I guess **to change their mind** is an infinitive clause being a complement of **slow**.

But I don't quite understand the meaning , does it mean :
These people change their mind slowly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does mean “These people change their mind(s) slowly”.* These people are very stubborn. It takes a lot of time to get them to change their points of view.

*You might not be wrong to use the singular, but I would use *minds* when talking about multiple people who each have their own mind. Not your question, but I thought this should be pointed out.